# ¿Como puedo colocar una imagen que tenga en una etiqueta <i>?

Tags: html, css

Estaria necesitando ver por que realmente me sale otro tipo de informacion, una forma de colocar en la etiqueta  de html un icono pero un icono MIO, una imagen MIA, y no encuentro informacion, alguno sabe si es posible eso? no quiero usar fontawesome ni nada, quiero poner MIS imagenes como icono por ejemplo, es posible esto? y si lo es que tengo que hacer?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con lo de [etiqueta `<i>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/i)?

Comment: Si quieres poner un icono tuyo ponlo como imagen y ya esta... no te hace falta usar la etiqueta **i** (que teoricamente es solo para mostrar caracteres en itálica, pero fontawesome y otros la usan en sus scripts para poner sus iconos).

Comment: justo por eso estaba en duda, que si se usa para poner en italica no se que sentido tenia que se usara el i, pensé en poner tambien la imagen que quisiera pero queria ver si habia una forma "correcta" de hacerlo, nada, coloco una imagen y fue jaaja, gracias.